# Why is getElementsByTagName not returning the elements with the tag name?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I am facing this strange problem that I have brought down to a MWE. I am not an expert in this, sorry if it is something obvious.

I have this HTML document:

```js
var floats = document.getElementsByTagName("custom-float");
for (var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
  var caption = floats[i].getElementsByTagName("float-caption");
  if (caption.length == 0) {
    throw 'This float has no caption!';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  A paragraph.
  <custom-float>
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <image src="1.svg"></image>
    </div>
    <float-caption>A description of the image.</float-caption>
  </custom-float>
</p>
```

For some reason when I open the HTML (both in Firefox 90.0 and Brave 1.26.77 in Linux) the `This float has no caption!` error is thrown, so this means that `getElementsByTagName` is not returning the `float-caption` element.

For my surprise, I noticed that if I remove the `<div style="display: flex;"></div>` wrapper and/or if I place the `</p>` before `<custom-float>`, everything works as expected. I.e. the following two HTML documents work fine:

```js
var floats = document.getElementsByTagName("custom-float");
for (var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
  var caption = floats[i].getElementsByTagName("float-caption");
  if (caption.length == 0) {
    throw 'This float has no caption!';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  A paragraph.
  <custom-float>
    <image src="1.svg"></image>
    <float-caption>A description of the image.</float-caption>
  </custom-float>
</p>
```

```js
var floats = document.getElementsByTagName("custom-float");
for (var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
  var caption = floats[i].getElementsByTagName("float-caption");
  if (caption.length == 0) {
    throw 'This float has no caption!';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  A paragraph.
</p>
<custom-float>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <image src="1.svg"></image>
  </div>
  <float-caption>A description of the image.</float-caption>
</custom-float>
```

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<p>`. Your MWE should be `<p><div>test</div></p>` with `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')` to find it's not there.

Comment: `<p><div></div></p>` is not valid HTML. You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<p>` and get consistent results from various browsers. Provide the browsers with valid HTML and they will behave better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your elements are being relocated in the DOM, because the given HTML is invalid: [`div` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) can't be inside [`p` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), which can only have *phrasing* content, not *flow* content like a `div`. If you inspect the structure with the DOM inspector in your browser, you'll see that the `div` and its contents have been moved out of the `p` (and thus out of the `custom-float`) into the `p`'s parent.

If you replace the `p` with a `div` (or remove the `div`, as you discovered), you don't have that problem, because the HTML is no longer invalid.

Here's replacing the `p` with a `div`:

```js
var floats = document.getElementsByTagName("custom-float");
for(var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
    var caption = floats[i].getElementsByTagName("float-caption");
    if (caption.length == 0) {
        throw 'This float has no caption!';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>MWE</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 
 <body>
    <div>
        A paragraph.
        <custom-float>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <image src="1.svg"></image>
            </div>
            <float-caption>A description of the image.</float-caption>
        </custom-float>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

It's easier to use querySelectorAll with just the tag

```js
var floats = document.querySelectorAll("custom-float");
for(var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++) {
    var caption = floats[i].querySelectorAll("float-caption");
    if (caption.length == 0) {
        throw 'This float has no caption!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help]. It's good of you to want to help, but please be sure your answer is really applicable to the question first -- posting speculative or incorrect answers is not useful. In this case, there are two problems: Using `querySelectorAll` isn't any easier than using `getElementsByTagName`, and switching from the one to the other does nothing to solve the problem the OP described.